# Trying to understand the VITERBI algorithm a bit better

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tagging, viterbi

I'm currently trying to implement the viterbi algorithm in python, more specifically the version presented in an online course.

As it stands, the algorithm is presented that way:
given a sentence with K tokens, we have to generate K tags .

We assume that tag K-1 = tag K-2 = '*', then for k going from 0 to K,
we set the tag for the token as follows :
tag(WORD_k) = argmax(p(k-1, tag_k-2, tag_k-1) * e( word_k, tag_k) * q(tag_k, tag_k-1, tag_k-1))

From my understanding this is straightforward because the p parameters are already calculated on each step (we go from 1 forward, and we already know p0), and max for the e and q params can be calculated by one iteration through the tags (since we can't come up with 2 different tags, we basically have to find the tag T for which the q * e product is maximal, and return that). This saves a lot of time, since we are almost at linear time in terms in big O notation, instead of exponential complexity, which we would get if we iterated through all possible word/tag combinations.

Am I getting the core of the algorithm correctly or am I missing something out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> since we can't come up with 2 different tags, we basically have to
>   find the tag T for which the q * e product is maximal, and return that

Yeah, sounds about right. `q` is the trigram (transition) probability and `e` is named the emission probability. As you said [image] is unchanged between different paths in each stage, so the max is only dependent on the other two.

Each tag sequence should start with two asterisks at positions `-2` and `-1`. So the first assumption is correct:

[image]

If we assume [image] to be the maximum probability that the last two tags at position `k` are `u` and `v`, based on what we just said about the beginning asterisks, the base case would be

[image] .

You had two errors in the general case though. The emission probability is a conditional. Also in the trigram, [image] is repeated two times and the formula given is incorrect:

[image]